# Medical questions

Tags: discussion, answers

How do we deal with questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/anyone-else-experiencing-vision-problems-from-xbox-kinect-laser), that are in the end medical questions. I'm not thinking about off-topic/on-topic, but about liability. Wrong medical advice on this site could cause legal trouble.

Is there an official SO policy about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same guidelines that you would for legal questions, and do has you have done in that question.

If you think it's a medical/legal problem simply state that fact. Don't offer any more advice other than that the OP consults a doctor/lawyer.

Comment: If you can see infrared you surely need to get your eyes checked...